# Running SSL and non-SSL sites simultaneously with MAMP (4.0.6)

Tags: apache, ssl, mamp, virtualhost, httpd.conf

To enable SSL, I've uncommented this line in httpd.conf:

```
# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

The httpd-ssl.conf file itself I've left untouched, and created .crt and .key files for a self-signed SSL certificate in the places it's expecting to see them by default:

```
SSLCertificateFile "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.key"
```

Back in the main httpd.conf, I've created a VirtualHost for a site I want to use SSL, and configured like this to eventually get it working:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/Users/jonnott/Documents/sslsite1.dev"
ServerName sslsite1.dev:443
ServerAlias www.sslsite1.dev
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

This SSL site now works fine.

However, the problem I have is that now whenever I try to visit any local non-SSL hosts, I get this error:

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
```

These other non-SSL sites are configured in httpd.conf like this:

```
<VirtualHost *> 
DocumentRoot "/Users/jonnott/Documents/site2.dev"
ServerName site2.dev
ServerAlias www.site2.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I missing / doing wrong?

Comment: Try limiting your SSL enabled virtuahost to port 443. Use `<VirtualHost *:443>` instead of `<VirtualHost *>`

Comment: To continue on what @AnandBhat said, you need two virtualhosts: one for http and the other for https. See http://serverfault.com/a/253247/367929 for an example of what it would look like.

Comment: @AnandBhat This doesn't make any different, unfortunately :(

Comment: @DavidDuponchel I understand that I need different VirtualHosts, but my issue is that if I have httd-ssl.conf included by httpd.conf, then ALL my non-SSL hosts get the 400 Bad Request response.

Comment: In the default httpd-ssl.conf there is a VirtualHost directive `<VirtualHost _default_:443> ... </VirtualHost>`, but if I remove it completely, then SSL stops working (and my non-SSL hosts are OK again). I don't know what the significance of `_default_` is, and I'm not aware there's a corresponding directive for `_default_` in the regular httpd.conf ??

Comment: What you describe looks like a `SSLEngine on` outside of a `<VirtualHost>`. Could you double your configuration for this ? Regarding `_default_:443`: with apache 2.4, [it's the same as `*:443`](http://serverfault.com/a/567398/367929).

Comment: ... or a `SSLEngine on` inside a `<VirtualHost>` that matches http requests. Could you also double check that you applied @AnandBhat fix and restarted apache ?

Comment: @DavidDuponchel see answer below..

Answer (score 2):

I think I've pretty much figured it out after reading this:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_faq.html#vhosts2

I needed BOTH of these in my httpd.conf before the start of my VirtualHost directives:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

..and then each VirtualHost needed to be port-specific:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Users/jonnott/Documents/Projects/site1"
ServerName site1.dev:80
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/Users/jonnott/Documents/Projects/site1"
ServerName site1.dev:443
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
```